# Android Java Recycler view swipe hint

Tags: java, android

I have a recycler view on android, I add a swipe on the left which is working perfectly, but the users complaint that they cannot know that this recycler view is swappable.
I need to swipe automatically the first row for 50dp, so the user can know that the can swipe to do an action.

Is there a way to do that on android java

Answer (score 0):

Most Android users know how to swipe.If recyclerview is not auto-refreshing, you can try showing the lists with livedata.All items saved and deleted with the help of an observer are automatically organized
If you search the internet, you can learn how to use recyclerview with livedata.